# Html5 - Callback when media is ready on iPad wont work

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html5-audio

I'm trying to add a callback to a HTML5 audio element on an iPad.
I added an `eventlistener` to the element, the `myOtherThing()` starts but there is no sound. If I pause and the play the sound again the audio starts. This works in Chrome. Does anyone have an idea how I can do this?

```
    myAudioElement.src = "path_to_file";
    addEventListener("canplay", function(){
        myAudioElement.play();
        myOtherThing.start();
    });
```

**SOLVED**

Just wanted to share my solution here, just in case someone else needs it. As far as I understand the iPad does not trigger any events without user interactions. So to be able to use "canply", "playing" and all the other events you need to use the built in media controller. Once you press play in that controller, the events gets triggered. After that you can use your custom interface.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Safari to begin loading the file. Plus, the `canplay` event [isn't supported on iOS](http://areweplayingyet.org/event-canplay). Just call `play` immediately after calling `load`.

```
myAudioElement.src = "path_to_file";
myAudioElement.load(); // Start loading the audio
myAudioElement.play();
```

Comment: Great site you linked to. I have tried this, but it is important that the audio is ready to play when I call myOtherThing(). So I kind of need a callback.